# Shorthand If without else in Razor view (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to check a boolean and then show an integer:

```
@( ViewBag.HaveBeenHere ? submission.DurationInMonths )
```

I am getting an error:

> CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected

I know the : is for the else, but in this case I don't have an else.

When I add it like this:

```
@( ViewBag.HaveBeenHere ? submission.DurationInMonths : "" )
```

I get this error:

> CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string'

How do I do a shorthand if statement to check a boolean and display an integer in the view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this if you wanted to keep the syntax:

```
@( ViewBag.HaveBeenHere ? submission.DurationInMonths.ToString() : "" )
```

Adding `ToString()` will, of course, make the return types the same.

Comment: @Jonesy they took it back, so I'm thinking they missed the `ToString()` I had added. Maybe I should call that out in my answer!

Comment: They haven't taken it back

Comment: Oh, hmm, oh well. It's not a big deal. I added the clarification regardless.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Can't believe I could have just done .ToString()!

Answer (score 5):

That short hand is for if-else so it just doesn't work here. You can just do;

```
@( if(ViewBag.HaveBeenHere) { submission.DurationInMonths; } )
```

and it's no longer. If you have a one liner you can just put it on the same line as the `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't.** Simply use an `if` statement.

```
@( if(ViewBag.HaveBeenHere) submission.DurationInMonths; )
```

[Conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> The conditional operator (?:) returns **one of two values** depending
>   on the value of a Boolean expression.